# Plotting live data from load cell with python

Tags: python, plot

I'm trying to plot live data with python from a load cell. The way I have it configured currently is with an Arduino uno transmitting the data to my PC via USB-serial port. I have written two different scripts (one for plotting data live from a csv, and one for writing the data from USB-serial to the same csv). The two scripts work fine by themselves, but won't work simultaneously when I try to integrate them into one script.

```
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

arduino_port = "/dev/cu.usbmodem21301"
baud = 57600
fileName = "test.csv"
samples = 2000
printLabels = False


fig = plt.figure()

ser = serial.Serial(arduino_port, baud)
file = open(fileName, "w")
file.close()
tid = 0

line = 0

def animate(i):
    f = open(fileName,'r')
    graph_data1 = f.read()
    lines1 = graph_data1.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for lin in lines1:
        if len(lin) > 1:
            x,y = lin.split(',')
            xs.append(int(x))
            ys.append(int(y))
    plt.plot(xs,ys)
    f.close()
    
start_time = time.time()

while line < samples:
    f = open(fileName, "a")
    getData = str(ser.readline())
    data = getData[2:][:-5]
    tid += 330
    print(data)
    f.write(str(tid) + ',' + data + "\n")
    line = line + 1
    f.close()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 1000)
    
    plt.show()
```

I have tried a few variations of handling the reading/writing to the csv-file, but it seems like there's a problem with the plot updating itself. I have tried using the plt.pause() function, that didn't work either.